# OneToOne mapping Hibernate - do not want to save data to the second table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two Entity one User(Owing entity - consists of field roleId as mapping between user and role) and other is Role.
Roles are already created in the database.
I have screen where in the User selects particular User Role on User creation.
When i save the data i only want to save user details along with the role Id in the User table. I do not want to save the role details as it is already present.

I am using Hibernate for persistence. Using @OneToOne mapping.

```
    @Entity   
    public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
        private String firstName;


        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String lastName;

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
            private Role role;

    }


@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String role;

}
```

Currently it is trying to save both User plus Role details. Which is not required.
Please help on how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you restrict the cascade to remove:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
```

Comment: Tries - Getting below  Exception Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: Yes, you should save your role first, before you want to save the user that has a reference to a unsaved role - which else ID should `User` save for the unsaved role?

Comment: Role is already present in the database i am just referring the same. I am just setting the RoleId in the role object in the User object and trying to save. If i fetch the Role and set it in User Object and try to save it works fine. But here i need to make and extra call to fetch the role details which is not required. How to avoid that?

Comment: Have you set the managed role object on the user object before saving the user object?